# error while using class method as callback in cpp

Tags: ros, c++, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm actually trying to use my own class method as callback of a topic.
I do it like this

First i created a publisher :

```
    ros::Publisher topicDirection = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("commandeDir", 1);
```

then  i  subscribe to this topic (commandeDir) with :

```
Servo pwmDir();
ros::Subscriber topicDir = n.subscribe("commandeDir", 1, &Servo::commande(const std_msgs::Float64& msg), pwmDir);
```

and my function looks like this :

```
void Servo::commande(const std_msgs::Float64& msg)
{
     //.......
}
```

it throw me this error :

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:138:31: error: ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘int’
 return M::__s_getDataType().c_str();
```

i  don't get what i am doing wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228215/error-while-using-class-method-as-callback-in-cpp/) by [pit](https://answers.ros.org/users/26163/pit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the very least, you don't include the method signature (just the function identifier) in the 3rd parameter when creating the subscriber (the `n.subscribe` call).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0